# How to get highlights in article before abstract and keywords?

Tags: formatting, article

Using the `cas-dc` document class I am trying to have the highlights of the article before the abstract and keywords in a two word document.[image] Like this picture shows.

I am using the template provided on elseviers website and using the code:

```
\begin{highlights}
\item Research highlights item 1
\item Research highlights item 2
\item Research highlights item 3
\end{highlights}
```

This places it on a page before like this picture shows:
[image]

Looking inside `cas-common.sty` I am able to find this code:

```
\RequirePackage{moreverb}

\tex_gdef:D \abstractname { A\,B\,S\,T\,R\,A\,C\,T }
\tl_new:N \l_stm_abs_title_tl
\box_new:N \g_stm_abs_box

\NewDocumentEnvironment { Abstract } { o }
{
%  \global\setbox \g_stm_abs_box = \vtop \bgroup 
%  \hsize = .65 \textwidth \parindent \z@
  \group_begin:
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { }
  { \tex_gdef:D \abstractname { #1 } }
  \parindent \z@
  \box_if_empty:NTF \g_stm_key_box
  { \leftskip = .35 \textwidth }
  {
    \dim_gset:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_ht:N \g_stm_key_box }
    \dim_gadd:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_dp:N \g_stm_key_box }
    \leftskip .35\textwidth
    \hspace*{-.35 \textwidth }
    \noindent\hbox_to_wd:nn {  \z@ } { \box \g_stm_key_box } 
    \skip_vertical:n { - \l_tmpa_dim } 
  }
  \noindent \abstractname \par
  \skip_vertical:n { -4pt}
  \noindent \rule{.65\textwidth}{.2pt}\par \footnotesize
  \ignorespaces \everypar { \parindent=1.5em }
}
{ \par \group_end: }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { PrelimsAbstract } { O{} }
  {\parindent=0pt 
   { \fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont #1 }\par
   \vskip12pt
   { \fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\bfseries\selectfont\casprelimstitle } \par
   \vskip6pt
   \seq_use:Nn \g_stm_prelimsau_seq { , }
   \vskip12pt
   \par 
  } 
  {}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment { abstract } { o }
{
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { }
   { \tex_gdef:D \abstracttitle { #1 } }
  \verbatimwrite{\jobname.abs}
}
{ \endverbatimwrite }

\newbox\casgrabsbox
\newbox\cashlsbox
\newbool { usecasgrabsbox }
\newbool { usecashlsbox }

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment { graphicalabstract } { O{Graphical~Abstract} }
{
 \global \booltrue { usecasgrabsbox }
 \global\setbox\casgrabsbox=\vbox\bgroup
  \begin{PrelimsAbstract}[#1]
  \noindent \ignorespaces
}
{
  \end{PrelimsAbstract}   
  \egroup
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { highlights } { O{Highlights} }
{
 \global \booltrue { usecashlsbox }
 \global\setbox\cashlsbox=\vbox\bgroup
  \begin{PrelimsAbstract}[#1]
  \noindent \ignorespaces
  \begin{itemize}
}
{
  \end{itemize}
  \end{PrelimsAbstract}   
  \egroup
}


\NewDocumentCommand \dashrule { O{.4pt} m m }
   {
     \color{black!50}
     \skip_vertical:n { #2 }
     \noindent \rule { \linewidth } { #1}
     \normalcolor \skip_vertical:n { #3 }
   }
```

I cannot seem to be able to fix this issue, however.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-doublec}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\title [mode = title]{title}                      
\author[1]{\color{black}First Author}[role=Researcher,
                            orcid=N/A]
\author[1]{\color{black}D}[%
   role=Supervisor]
    \begin{highlights}
 \item Research highlights item 1
 \item Research highlights item 2
 \item Research highlights item 3
 \end{highlights}

\begin{abstract}
    abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
    keywords
\end{keywords}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Minimum working example

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Even their example shows the highlights on a separate page (https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/cas-dc-template.pdf)